# Dispatch of constructor in R (S3)

Tags: r, constructor, dispatch

Is it ok from architectural point of view to dispatch the constructor in R (S3 system)?

I have a constructor for class `returns` and I want to dispatch it in a way like: `returns.zoo`, `returns.data.frame` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion, but I think there is (unwritten) convention to use `as` prefix in this case. For example: `as.data.frame` coerces various objects to a data frame.
Same with `as.matrix`, `as.Date` and `as.list` ...

Often a "non-`as`" function calls the generic `as` function (e.g. `data.frame` function calls `as.data.frame`).

There is also a good practice to implement a function with `is` prefix.
For example: `is.data.frame`, `is.list`.

**But** sometimes this is not so. For example `formula` is a generic "coercer" 
and `as.formula` is not. And there are a lot of packages with combined practice. For example `igraph` includes `as.igraph` generic but uses `from_data_frame` to create object from a data frame.

So I guess `as.returns.zoo` will look aligned with existing practice but
`returns.zoo` is not wrong either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Couple of questions: `is` prefix is for testing whether or not the class is "something_after_dot", right? So, it has nothing to do with constructor, it is just nice to implement. Did I understand correctly? My constructor does not only coerce, but doing some computation inside ( calculating rates of returns from prices). Even though it is better to name it with prefix  `as`?

Comment: Yes, the _is_ prefix is another story. I don't think there are objective and sharp borders between constructing, coercing, transforming and "calculating something". Sometimes you have to decide for yourself. If you think the function is doing something beside constructing or coercing then find the right verb and name it appropriately. The only criteria is if users quickly understand what it is doing,